# Simple SOQL query give different result based on the fields contained in the query. Whats happen?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm receiving a bug from an production enviroment that is totally strange for me. The same query give different results based on the fields present in the query. I give you an example on the query Made:

```
Select id, LogisticaContatto__c From order  where id='801w0000003OaluAAC'
```

This Query returns 0 results.

While the same query without the custom field returns correctly the record, as expected.

```
Select id From order  where id='801w0000003OaluAAC'
```

the custom field `LogisticaContatto__c`is an formula field that reads some values via lookup. This is happening with only this field.

I'm not understanding what is happening. Do you have any similar experience and a reasonable logic that this should happen?

The logic on the formula field is this

```
IF(TEXT(Type__c)='Constant1',
                IF( NOT( ISBLANK(Inst__r.PersonMobilePhone)),Inst__r.PersonMobilePhone,
            IF( NOT( ISBLANK(Inst__r.Phone)),Inst__r.Phone,
                IF( NOT( ISBLANK(Inst__r.PersonHomePhone)),Inst__r.PersonHomePhone,
                    Inst__r.PersonOtherPhone
                )
            )
        )
,
    IF( Account.RecordType.Name ='Business',  Account.Phone ,
        IF( NOT( ISBLANK(Account.PersonMobilePhone)),Account.PersonMobilePhone,
            IF( NOT( ISBLANK(Account.Phone)),Account.Phone,
                IF( NOT( ISBLANK(Account.PersonHomePhone)),Account.PersonHomePhone,
                    Account.PersonOtherPhone
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

thanks.

Comment: I'm proceeding also to ask to Salesforce support, anyway was a case never seen and i was not able to find corresponding results on web, so i posted it here.

Comment: Does the user have permissions over the custom field (LogisticaContatto__c) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm running as system admin, and i have the permission. Usually if you don't have permission is generated an error.

Comment: Did you run both query in developer console ? Same result ?

Comment: have you checked the logs of the developer console, perhaps it is thowing an exception ?

Comment: Hi @ransommule, thanks for your suggestions.  Yes I already debugged and tested them. The behaviours comes after debugging an new issue  that faced to users. Debugging the code and logic i come to this result, that SOQL has an unknown behaviour to me. The strange fact is that the code is running by like 16 months in production, and only today generated this issue.

Comment: I asked that, because as far as i know, there is no reason to have differents resutls to the same query.

Comment: so, either it a permission issue or is a exception issue

Comment: @ransommule If it was running for 16 months and and stopped working today, either there's an issue with his instance or he's changed something in his org that's causing it. If the issue is with his instance, he'll need help from Salesforce Support to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened a case with support about this yesterday. It has been acknowledged as a bug and they will be rolling back the patch that caused it.

Comment: did they provide any additional detail as to what caused it?

Comment: Nothing other than that a recent patch caused the problem. I noticed the issue in my sandboxes yesterday and then in my production org today. I just received confirmation (and tested for myself) that the issue is resolved in my sandbox. still occurs in my production org though.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up on this question. Interesting bug or was it WAD but just designed poorly...hmmm.

Comment: I also opened a bug, I'm waiting a feedback from them.  @mkdjns can you give your case id or case number, so i can share directly to support to boost the solution? Thnks.

Comment: My case number is 15090902.